# Adding key for average values in nested dictionary lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension, key-value

I have a dictionary of keys of dates. Each date has a key:value pair of a project and a list of days.

I would like to add an average metric to each date key, while removing outliers above 6. My code is close, but produces some screwy results.

```
import numpy as np
d = {}
d['1/2/15'] = {'Project 1' : [1,4,7], 'Project 2' : [1,5, 11]}

for key, value in d.iteritems():
    avg =  np.mean([x for x in d[key]['Project 1'] if x < 6])
    d[key][str(value) + ' Average'] = avg

print d
```

Expected Output:

```
{'Project 1' : [1,4,7], 'Project 1 Average' : 2.5, 'Project 2' : [1,5,7], 'Project 2 Average' : 3.0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
d = {}
d['1/2/15'] = {'Project 1' : [1,4,7], 'Project 2' : [1,5, 11]}

for key, value in d.iteritems():
        d_avg = {}
        for k, v in value.iteritems():
            avg =  np.mean([x for x in d[key][k] if x < 6])
            d_avg[str(k) + ' Average'] = avg
        d[key].update(d_avg)

print d
```

output

```
{'1/2/15': {'Project 2 Average': 3.0, 'Project 2': [1, 5, 11], 'Project 1 Average': 2.5, 'Project 1': [1, 4, 7]}}
```

the problem is dictionary cannot be updated while iterating through it.

Comment: This is is an interesting solution, but you hardcoded k in the key naming, so it only calculates the average for Project 2. Is there a way to have that do it for both Projects?

Comment: just replaced it with `k`, i see the problem now, i will double check the code.

Comment: sorry, I don't follow you.

Comment: i see the problem now, i will modify the answer shortly.

Comment: should be right now. do you want to permanently remove the outliers value or just don't count it in the average?

Comment: just not count in the average. I may want to original data source later. Looking at your solution, it looks very obvious, but it a challenge to figure out as a new programmer! Thanks!